# Have a default project folder different from the workspace in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I was always told that it is a best practice to create your projects outside of Eclipse's workspace.

But it gets not really convenient when you want to import an existing project or creating a new one, to each time browse to your "projects" folder instead of the default "workspace" folder that Eclipse suggests.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse "yes, my workspace is in C:\Users\David\workspace" but all my projects must be created in C:\dev\projects" ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'create your projects outside of Eclipse's workspace' or why that would be best practice.  However, I do find that File > Import Projects > Browse For Folder dialog is extremely clumsy.  For example, I have a number of source project files which for organizational purposes are stored in another part of the drive,  and the "Browse For Folder" dialog always defaults to the desktop (Windows 7) and I have to tediously navigate down multiple levels to get to the actual files.  The interface does not even see shortcuts, so we cannot create shortcuts!

Comment: Hi Dell, that's exactly what I am talking about.


Usually my workspace is in something like C:\David\eclipse-workspace but I keep my projects in D:\projects because I want to be able to ditch an Eclipse workspace easily.


And each time I want to import a project I have to go through the same painful process as you !